# Big numbers in Python

Tags: python, numbers, digits

I am working in a problemas involving the e number . So I found this webpage which has 1000000 digits of the e number and I copy pasted to Python IDL. In the instant I pasted it froze and its still like that. I don't how long would it be or if it will harm the computer (I'm working in a MacBook Pro which is not mine).Also I can't shut down the computer because the program is working. So can someone tell me  what will happend and how long this may last and if there is a way to stop the program. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just press `ctrl+c` to exit out of the interpreter!

Comment: Did not work for me. I mean, its completely freeze. I can use every other program but I can't use Python or shut it down.

Comment: Try `cmd+Q`, which will quit the program. If the laptop is completely frozen though...

Comment: No, the laptop isn't frozen, the program is. I'm talking to you through the laptops Chrome. And no, it did not work what you told me.

Comment: @FedericoCollasius You can try force quitting it (Command-Option-Escape) and then killing the program.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in many digits, [Sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html) might be useful. You can calculate *e* to a 1000000 digits with (needs a couple minutes to compute):

```
import sympy as sy

print(sy.E.evalf(n=1000000))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I already fix the problem but I will take your advice.

Comment: Python can deal with large numbers without Sympy. Sympy if for *symbolic* computation (ex sqrt(8) = 2 * sqrt(2)), not for large numbers operations.

Answer (score 0):

Python should accept numbers with 100 digits as input without problem. But to actually use numbers with so high precision, you should use the `decimal` module of Python Standard Library. Example :

```
import decimal
n = decimal.Decimal('1.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890')
n2 = n + n
print(n2)
```

=> `Decimal('2.246913578024691357802469135780246913578024691357802469135780246913578024691357802469135780246913578')`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will take your advice.